# Cannot read/open zip bigger than 2GB

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, php-ziparchive

I'm not able to open a zip file that is bigger than 2GB. Any ideas why is this happening?
I'm getting Error code 5 also `getStatusString` returns `Undefined property: ZipArchive::$getStatusString`
I think is OS issue.

Comment: We need more info, i am not sure if it is a php ini problem

Comment: I can upload unlimited size of files. I have full access to server. Only can't open zip file that is larger thant 2GB.
Is zip open the file into RAM with same GB??

Comment: I dont know that :S Maybe something related to x64 / x32 OS ?

Comment: have you tried command line zip tools

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 Xenial x32 2GB of Ram.

Comment: @Dagon I need to user ZipArchive PHP and not SSH. For better control into unzip.

Comment: you can call the os functions from php, sometimes its the better approach even if the job *can* be done in php

Comment: Reading this, http://php.net/manual/en/zip.constants.php apparently you have some reading problem, maybe OS related because of GB.

Comment: @P0lT10n That's I'm saying maybe OS or RAM. If I try to unzip lower than 2GB files is working fine.

Comment: @Dagon I have a big script to unzip files with the way I want to. I can't create this whole thing to run into SSH commands. Will take too long. I though that way before.

Comment: Does anyone knows about -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64?